# Apache web server error attempting to start services

Tags: apache, xampp

Whenever I try to start Apache it pop a new box  named User Account Control and after clicking yes button In xampp control panel it shows

*Attempting to start services......*

[png of xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bFqU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the port 80 is in use first as this can be an issue. You can do this by typing "netstat -an" into cmd. Then look for 0.0.0.0:80 under Local Address.

If you find something using that port than you will need to stop that application or configure xxamp to use another port.

You can also try running as admin as this does seem to help.